# connecting with web server using android app & nfc tag

Tags: android, database, server, nfc

I want to build an android app, that when you put your phone on nfc tag, the app connect to server (I suppose database will be in web server) and get the data from database, and when you put a phone on second nfc tag it connect again to server, but this time gets diffrent data from database(must be there new database).
So basically I' am new to servers and databases and if this is posible what I mention above or at least a similar. Can you provide me with some tutorials that I can learn from and will help me build this.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the following link,

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

It has all the tutorials on how to utilize NFC on Android. It has certain API's available as well which you can use. The part where first it does a different operation and the next time a different one all depends on you on how you deal with it. You can write a condition based on a boolean value to see if its a first time or second.

Hope this helps.